# Rails : jump to function chosen at realtime (variable name)

Tags: ruby, call

I would like to jump to an "import function" which can be one off the file I already wrote in lib/import/...

The user chooses an option in a select box and from this choice, I want to execute a specific portion of code on one uploaded file (import excel with different possible layouts)

I wrote this :

```
# Loading and executing the template chosen by user at step 1
template_path = 'import/'+params[:template]+'/import.rb'
require template_path
Import.action(filename, session, params, current_project)
```

I have several import.rb files located each in a separate directory. One of these is :

```
module Import
require 'spreadsheet'

     def Import.action(filepath, session, params, project)
            # My import code
     end
 end
```

The problem is that Rails is always calling the action method from **the first directory** in lib/firstdirectory/import.rb

I never reach another import.rb file located in lib/otherdirectory/import.rb

- Is there a better way to execute a "jump to" functionnality in realtime ?
- Why does Rails jump to always the same function ?

Edit :

My application.rb configuration file contains

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/import/**/"]
```

Edit 2 :

```
# lib/importer/importer.rb
module Importer
  class Base
    # Whatever common logic the import.rb files have.
  end
end

#lib/importer/Import_test/import_test.rb    Note the Big letter for the directory (constant)
module Importer
  class Import_test < Base
    def self.import
        logger.debug(">>>>>>>>>>>>>  special function Test <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<")   
    end
  end
end

# Call from controller
logger.debug "------------------>> "+params[:template]
raise "Invalid input" unless params[:template].constantize.superclass == Importer::Base
params[:template].constantize.import()
```

The params[:template] returns the string Importer::Import_test  (with capital letters)

I get the error :
NoMethodError (undefined method 'superclass' for Importer::Import_test:Module):
  app/controllers/import_controller.rb:57:in `step2'

Comment: try `load` instead of `require` needless to say this perhaps architecture flaw where you depend on user input to decide what file to load data from the external world cannot easily be tested think of a better way 2 do this is all I would suggest for u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code using the first directory entry makes sense. When you reference a constant whose definition has not yet been loaded, Rails checks the entries in `autoload_paths` for a corresponding file. Since you already have that `import.rb` in your first directory, your application loads that file.

A better design for this IMHO would be something along:

```
config.autoload_paths += ["#{config.root}/lib"]

# lib/importer.rb
module Importer
  class Base
    # Whatever common logic the import.rb files have.
  end
end

# lib/importer/foo.rb
module Importer
  class Foo < Base
    def self.import
      # ...
    end
  end
end

# lib/importer/bar.rb
module Importer
  class Bar < Base
    def self.import
      # ...
    end
  end
end

# In your view, a way to identify these:
select_tag :layout, options_for_select({
  "Foo" => "Importer::Foo",
  "Bar" => "Importer::Bar"
})

# In your controller:
raise "Invalid input" unless params[:layout].constantize.superclass == Importer::Base
params[:layout].constantize.import( ... )
```

**Update**:

Rails looks for files this way: Say you want to use `FooBar::Baz`. If it doesn't have `FooBar` yet, it will load `lib/foo_bar.rb` and there is supposed to be something there. Next, it will try to access `FooBar::Baz`. Only if it doesn't have that yet (already after loading `lib/foo_bar.rb`), it will load `lib/foo_bar/baz.rb` and there is supposed to be something there.

If you want to use `autoload_paths` and not require ruby files yourself, please use the convention of using proper camelcase that Rails can easily change to underscore. e.g. Use camelcase ImporterTest without the underscore and have `lib/importer/importer_test.rb` so the framework will be able to find the correct file and your definition.

:-) Good luck.

Comment: Thnak you for answering. I tried today your idea and I get the following error : undefined method `superclass' for Importer::Import_test:Module   . I've edit the question to give you more information ! Thank you !

Comment: Hi Stephane. In the design that I suggested, the importers are classes that inherit from `Importer::Base`. Note within the `Importer` module: `class Foo < Base`.

Comment: Do you have anything in `lib/importer/importer_test.rb`? Please search for the text `Importer_test` in your app, I think your application is loading `Importer::Importer_test` from elsewhere and not using the class definition in the new file.

Comment: Hi kristinalim. Thank you for answering. I've implemented your solution in my app. Did you see my edit number 2 under the question ? It is the code I have for now (it is mainly your solution). Can you have a look if you have the time ? Many thanks !

Comment: Hi. I've just understand what's wrong. It is the access to my file lib/importer/Import_test/importer.rb    The Base class in lib/ is correctly loaded by config.autoload_paths += ["#{config.root}/lib"]  but the extended class Import_test is not accessible. If I place the Import_test Class definition code under the Class Base, it is working... How can I get access to the sub-class ?

Comment: Added more details about the autoload constant filename convention. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are much better ways. I suggest having a hash of template names to objects that execute the action. Import all your importers, and construct the hash. Than use the hash to get the function, and execute it.